# What happens when you want to close a gate but there's another investigator in Other World?

Tags: arkham-horror

What happens if you enter a gate and, later before closing, another investigator enters the same gate?

You are returned to Arkham but the other investigator would be in the Another World trying to return to the same gate that you will try to close.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the gate the second investigator came through (or another gate to the same world) is open when they try to return, then they would return as normal to whichever gate they choose.

However, if there are no open gates to that Other World, then the investigator would be lost in time and space. For reference, this is on page 8 of the Arkham Horror rulebook, under the **Other World Movement** section.